# Any cheap and easy ways to isolate analog signals?

Tags: analog, isolation, transducer

I want to isolate some transducer signals. Everything I've looked up is pretty expense/requires a lot of supporting circuitry which, because of volume, is not ideal. What is the easiest/cheapest way to isolate analog signals?

Comment: What is the bandwidth of the signals? What is the dynamic range of the signals? What do you consider "cheap" and "expensive"?

Comment: Isolate from what?

Comment: @ThePhoton Bandwidth < 1Khz, signal range 0 to 12V, preferably a few dollars to isolate 1 signal.

Comment: You might want to look into the H11F1, an analog optocoupler with an FET output. But it is limited to DC-audio and is linear only from 50uA to 500uA at the FET.

Comment: Sometimes it’s better to digitize the signals and transfer them over a digital isolated interface such as I2C (with an isolator chip).

Comment: I've used a long plastic stick attached to the knob of a variac to isolate analog signals.

Comment: You have to constrain your problem. Do you have a power supply available on the signal side or are you adding a power supply to your costs? What is the desired resolution (i.e., bits or SNR)? What is the output impedance of your sources, can these drive circuitry? Do you care about dead zones near zero or Vdd? What degree of isolation (i.e., medical, safety, functional)? Etc.

Comment: bandwidh ok, but what's the frequency? is that 0 to 1kHz or 110-111kHz ? how much precision do you need? how much noise is acceptable?

Comment: where is the signal going next?

Comment: is what you are looking for something like this [signal isolator](https://www.globalspec.com/learnmore/data_acquisition_signal_conditioning/signal_conditioning/signal_isolators)

Answer (score 1):

Isolation amplifiers could be a solution. Pricing starts at 2~3€. Given the simple requirements you seem to have, cheap ones could suffice.

See [there](https://www.mouser.fr/Semiconductors/Amplifier-ICs/Isolation-Amplifiers/_/N-4fs2k?FS=True&Ns=Pricing|0), sorted by price.